# isAlive() method of java thread is not working properly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying a example of `isAlive()` method of java threading. But i found that `isAlive()` method is returning `false` even if thread has been already started. Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong? Here is the code snippet.

```
package app;

public class ThreadAliveDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread myThread;

        myThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println("My Thread.");
            }
        };

        myThread.setName("My Thread");
        myThread.start();

        if(!myThread.isAlive())
        {
            myThread.setName("My Thread");
            myThread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: use Thread.getState() instead, it provides extra info. starting a thread twice has no effect either.

Comment: Regarding @bestsss advice: Brian Goetz's book, Java Concurrency in Practice, says, "The result of Thread.getState should not be used for concurrency control, and is of limited
usefulness for testing. Its primary utility is as a source of debugging information."

Comment: @WoodenKitty, while a thread has not been started getState() would be stable (may need some sync. with the thread start). Goetz's advice is a very solid one but it's not applicable in this very case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory serves me well java has quite long periods between thread switching so it is possible that the isAlive fails because the thread is *not yet* alive. Try to add some waiting time between thread.start() and thread.isAlive()

Comment: I tried making thread sleep for 3 seconds but getting the same problem.

Comment: try to make the calling thread sleep for a second (_and_ let the child thread sleep 3 seconds)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that this behaviour is very unuseful?

Comment: I prefer using the comment on the original quesiton of getState() instead of adding wait time before checking isAlive().  Race conditions are never, never good.

Comment: I wonder if it's so much that the thread takes a long time to switch. The test code block comes immediately after the call to `start()`. You can hardly expect the test to produce reliable results. Assuming, of course, that the thread state is set asynchronously from the main thread, which appears to be the case.

Answer (score 12):

There's a good chance the thread will have started, executed, and finished, between your call to `start()` and your call to `isAlive()`.

Java offers no guarantees on the sequence in which these things happen. It could execute the spawned thread immediately, or it may choose to defer it until a bit later.

Incidentally, your code is trying to re-start the thread after it has died. This is [not permitted](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> It is never legal to start a thread
>   more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it
>   has completed execution.

So calling `start()` after checking `isAlive()` is never going to work.

Comment: Aye... I need to wrap a `synchronized` block around my brain and my fingers

Comment: No, i tried using Thread.sleep(3000); call inside the run method. Still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: But how come? i have made my thread sleep for 3 secs. and then checked the isAlive() call. And i think in this case isAlive() call must return true but it is still returning true result.

Comment: @Rupesh: How do you know what value it's returning? Your code inside the `if` block doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have placed breakpoint at if block and then checked what value does myThread.isAlive() returning.

Comment: @Rupesh: And you can do all of this in 3 seconds? Using a manual debugger is only going to make your timing problems worse. Your code, as written, is already broken (as pointed out), and you you *really* need to avoid using coincidence to make sure your thread timings work as expected.

Comment: Sir consider the 3 seconds sleep time as the time required to complete the execution of child thread. My concern is about why am i getting improper results after isAlive() call.

Comment: @Rupesh: I understand that. What I'm telling you is that program is *fundamentally flawed*. You can't do that sort of loose coding with threads and expect to get useful results.

Comment: I like the comment on the original question better, using getState() instead of isAlive(), in case the thread hasn't started yet.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any multithreading in java yet, but it looks to me like your thread probably will have run and exited before the isAlive() check. After all, looks like your thread just prints something out and then dies.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me recently, fixed it using

```
if(yourThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW){    
    yourThread.start();
}
```

instead of yourThread.isAlive();

Comment: Your answer doesn't really contribute anything that has not already been mentioned in previous answer and/or comments, posted some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the code you have posted. Thread.start() starts the thread: you don't need to start it twice. I don't see how your code can realistically into a situation where it has a Thread and doesn't know whether it has been started or not; anyway there are plenty of ways to code around that so it can't happen.

Comment: It's not about using the code as is in a real life situation but it is about making the concepts clear.

Comment: But all it means is that the thread hasn't actually started when start() returns. It's asynchronous you know. I don't see what concept is being illustrated.