# How to break out of a loop when no more threads are active

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a program where I initialize and start a variable number of threads. I need the main program to interact with the threads so I put those inside an infinite loop. After all the threads have died though I would like a way to break the loop. Here goes part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//some random initializing

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){     //p1 is a Runnable
        Thread t = new Thread(p1, "t"+ Integer.toString(i));
        t.start();
} 
while(true){
//do some stuff while threads are active
//not sure what if statement to put here to break loop
}
```

I can post more of my code if I need to, but I think it would be largely irrelevant.

Comment: you can check the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066160/java-threads-and-main-thread

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: How about creating threadgroup and using method getActiveCount() ??

Comment: The reason I didn't use a thread group is this is for a homework assignment on multi-threading. I am only suppose to use the basic .start(), .wait(), and .notify(). To organize my threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an array of Threads, to check them later on if they are done, then go through the same for loop but also set the values in the threads array. Finally, in the while loop, I would check if all the threads are not done using the state method of the thread - [How to check if thread is terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910548/how-to-check-if-thread-is-terminated)

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[num];

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){     //p1 is a runnable.
        Thread t = new Thread(p1, "t"+ Integer.toString(i));
        threads[i-1] = t;
        t.start();
} 

while(!allThreadsCompleted(threads)) {
 // do some of your code here
}

public static boolean allThreadsCompleted(Thread[] threads) {
    for(int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if(threads[i].getState()!=Thread.State.TERMINATED)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I realize now that this would be useful if you actually want to do something in the while loop, not just for stalling purposes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this looks like I should be able to get it to work now.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)(since java 1.5) here, tt is a synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

Snippet:

```
CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(num);
...
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){     //p1 is a Runnable
        Thread t = new Thread(p1, "t"+ Integer.toString(i),signal);
        t.start();
} 
signal.await();           // wait for all to finish
```

... In `run()` Method of your Thread...

```
public void run(){
       ...                // do stuff
       signal.countDown(); // sending signal that work has done.
}
```

Comment: +1.  Also, if you want to do something while waiting (as OP wants), you could go. `while (latch.getCount() > 0) { do stuff }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stalling with a while loop, just `join` all the threads. The join method essentially just waits for the thread to finish.

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[num];
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    Thread t = new Thread(p1, "t"+ Integer.toString(i));
    threads[i] = t;
    t.start();
} 

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    threads[i].join();
}
```

For more info consult the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Comment: If you want to do something in the while loop, wouldn't the join block the main thread?

Comment: @Bucco Indeed. I made the assumption that the wile loop was just for stalling purposes.

Comment: The loop in the main method actually interacts with the running threads so I don't think this will help me.