# Thread is already running when it is already stopped

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my download manager, I auto-pause the download when the activity is paused or stop. Any running downloads are interrupted. I know I should let it download even in background but that is not the point here.

The thing is, on resume, the download must continue. However, I get an exception that the thread is already running when in logcat I have a log that I placed which clearly says thread is interrupted.

The line pointed to is of the `Scheduler` class which is responsible for running the threads:

```
public class Scheduler extends TimerTask {
    private static int index = 0;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(Sharable.isResumed()){ // activity is ready for interaction with user
                if(Sharable.getShouldLook()){ // and we are ready to download
                    while(index < Sharable.downloads.size()){
                        Task t = Sharable.downloads.get(index++);
                        Log.v("SCHEDULER", "CHECKING");
                        if(t.getReadiness()==true && t.getProgress() != 100){
                            Log.v("TASK-- ", t.toString() + " is not running. Now starting");
                            if(!t.isAlive()){ // check if not already running
                                t.start(); // start the thread
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    index = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
```

`t.start()` is the culprit. **WHY?** I do not know why.

So what is in the logcat ?

```
08-21 15:50:54.316: V/TASKPATH(1460): /sdcard/tqa-se3ep47.mp3
08-21 15:50:54.386: V/TASK(1460): SETTING PATH
08-21 15:50:54.437: V/TASK(1460): MAKING URL
08-21 15:50:54.437: V/TASK(1460): MAKING CONNECTION
08-21 15:50:54.466: V/TASK(1460): Range:bytes=16636099-
08-21 15:50:54.466: V/TASK(1460): BYTES-WRITTEN: 16636099
08-21 15:50:54.514: V/TASK(1460): CONTENT-LENGTH: 27452333
08-21 15:50:55.326: V/TASK(1460): CONNECTED
08-21 15:50:56.886: V/TASK(1460): CODE: 206
08-21 15:50:56.886: V/TASK(1460): Partial Content
08-21 15:50:56.896: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16636099

.... some useless logs skipped for sake of sanity ....
08-21 15:51:00.986: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16763075
08-21 15:51:01.036: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.046: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16765123
08-21 15:51:01.056: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.196: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16767171
08-21 15:51:01.196: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.246: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16769219
08-21 15:51:01.246: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.266: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16771267
08-21 15:51:01.286: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.426: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16773315
08-21 15:51:01.437: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.486: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16775363
08-21 15:51:01.516: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.546: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16777411
08-21 15:51:01.546: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.586: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16779459
08-21 15:51:01.586: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.616: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16781507
08-21 15:51:01.616: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:01.676: V/TASK(1460): Writing at location 16783555
08-21 15:51:01.887: V/TASK(1460): 61.0
08-21 15:51:02.106: V/TASK(1460): INTERRUPTED
08-21 15:51:12.319: V/TASK--(1460): tqa-se3ep47.mp3 is not running. Now starting
```

The last line shows that the scheduler is starting the thread. It will start in the same way as the log shows. Set path, URL, etc.  This is what happens in `onResume()`. If I were to close and restart the app, it goes all good.

Error log:

```
08-21 15:51:12.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): FATAL EXCEPTION: Scheduler
08-21 15:51:12.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1460): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
08-21 15:51:12.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
08-21 15:51:12.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at com.example.simpledownloader.scheduler.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:23)
08-21 15:51:12.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Valid code ? How do I post an SSCCE of 8 classes ? Man, this is absurd. Did I not post the problematic code ?

Comment: It is not our responsibility to reduce your code to the problem for you.

Comment: @DeadMG Fair enough but that is also not a reason for a `close` vote. is the code provided not sufficient ? :)

Comment: I have no idea what TimerTask, Sharable or Task are, but if they are not framework-provided classes, then no. Here's a simple hint: If I paste your code into a Java IDE, then it's not going to compile *because there's no Main method*, at the very least.

Comment: Can you run this to reproduce problem? No? Then it's not sufficient.

Comment: @DeadMG Oh, I thought the comments were made it clear :)

Comment: @LittleChild: My Java IDE cannot execute or interpret your comments into an executable program.

Comment: @DeadMG Ok, so simple question: Why did the thread not start after it was interrupted ? I just `return` from `run()` if thread is interrupted.

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3140745/823393) answer interesting. It warns against using `isAlive` as a check to see if the thread has completed because a thread can often take a long while to start.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes, I am trying to restart a thread after it has 'died'. How do I 'resurrect' it ?

Comment: @DeadMG Maybe I posted something against the SO rules, I am also sure the  way you are talking is also against the SO rules. :) I get it that I am not as experienced as you are but that is no reason to use profanity :)

Comment: @LittleChild: Unsurprisingly, when people tell you that you asked a question that they cannot possibly answer, if you just ask the question again, they get a bit angry. Welcome to dealing with humans rather than machines. Fix your code sample and try again.

Comment: @DeadMG Ok, guide me as to how to post an SSCCE for an Android activity and I shall fix it.. and please do not assume that I am a machine. Humans get angry when they get cussed at and .. [**I AINT EVEN MAD**](http://funnymemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/I-aint-even-mad.jpg) +1 for your above comment

Comment: @LittleChild - If a thread has died you should take it to a quiet place and bury it. Start a new one if you like but don't expect a dead one to resurrect. Sounds to me like you should be using a ThreadPool.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon You are the less grumpy one even though your name says otherwise. :-) +1 for something which made sense to me :) *Basically, you can only call start() once*

Answer (score 1):

Avoid at any cost using Worker Threads, use an AsyncTask instead for a better control of the Thread's lifecycle.

Comment: Sure, `AsyncTask` is an option but I would just like to know why this happened. How could it have been solved

Comment: Depending on where your thread is started and stopped; if the UI is being changed (orientation, navigation, whatever) your Thread might be stuck or running several instances. Worker Threads are not a good idea if you want to communicate with the UI or manage them in the main thread.