# Why is this program creating more threads than possible?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is for a custom UDTF in a hive query, `CreateLogTable` is the UDTF class which I am using as a temp for testing. I am creating one thread per `file to be downloaded from Amazon S3` and waiting until another thread becomes available before allocating another file to the thread.

**Main Test logic**:

```
CreateLogTable CLT = new CreateLogTable();

int numThreads = 2;
int index = 0;
DownloadFileThread[] dlThreads = new DownloadFileThread[numThreads];
for (S3ObjectSummary oSummary : bucketKeys.getObjectSummaries()) {
    while (dlThreads[index] != null && dlThreads[index].isAlive()) {
        index += 1;
        index = index % numThreads;
    }
    dlThreads[index] = new DownloadFileThread(CLT , getBucket(oSummary.getBucketName() + "/"
                    + oSummary.getKey()), getFile(oSummary.getKey()), index);
    dlThreads[index].start();
    index += 1;
    index = index % numThreads;
}
```

**Thread class** (`run()` method):

```
try {
    System.out.println("Creating thread " + this.threadnum);
    this.fileObj = this.S3CLIENT.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(this.filePath, this.fileName));
    this.fileIn = new Scanner(new GZIPInputStream(this.fileObj.getObjectContent()));
    while (this.fileIn.hasNext()) {         
        this.parent.forwardToTable(fileIn.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Finished " + this.threadnum);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("Downloading of " + this.fileName + " failed.");
}
```

The while loop before the thread creation should be looping until it finds a `null thread` or a `dead thread` until it exits the loop, in which case a `new thread` will be created and started. Since I included logging to console, I am able to observe this process, but the output is unexpected:

```
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Creating thread 0
...
Creating thread 1
Creating thread 0
Creating thread 1
Finished 0
Finished 1
Finished 1
Finished 0
Finished 1
Finished 1
...
Finished 0
Finished 1
Finished 0
Finished 1
```

The above is only the first few lines of output. The issue is that more than two threads are created before any threads complete their tasks.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why you are not using thread pool - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html?

Comment: I will check it out and consider using it if I can't fix this issue. I would just like the get this working at the moment. @Jimilian

Comment: Actually, using an executor would be the best option. It's specifically meant for this sort of task.

Comment: Is that what Roey did in his example? @chrylis

Comment: You want to use a (ThreadPool) executor, because it contains a reasonable implementation of the kind of logic you want to implement.

Comment: According you question, did you have something like `Thread.sleep` in your while cycle? Could you show this part of code?

Comment: No, the above code is taken straight out of the test class's source, no modification was done @Jimilian

Comment: Thanks, yea I will be checking it out and implementing it. But why does this code have this behaviour? It just doesn't make sense to me @FelixLeipold

Comment: Yes, Roey has an example of the sort of thing I mean. Thread management is hard, and the JRE already has a good implementation.

Comment: How about the threads throw an exception other than `IOException` or `HiveException` and die silently? Catch `Throwable` to be sure.

Comment: I've always thought that catching such a generic exception was bad practice, but I did change my code to catch throwable and no, the threads are not throwing any errors @DanAllen

Comment: @ylun.ca are you sure that you posted the code that you ran? You could add some logging to see the values of  dlThreads[index].isAlive() and  dlThreads[index] != at the top of the outer loop.

Comment: @ylun.ca For debugging who cares? However for threads it's important to make sure any exception thrown out of it will get picked up somewhere.

Comment: @FelixLeipold I found the culprit, `.isAlive()` is always returning false... but why? the threads are clearly processing data through the run method. I can prove this by changing the `this.parent.forwardToTable(fileIn.nextLine());` in the Thread to a `System.out`. Shouldn't `isAlive()` return true if the `run()` method is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to see this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
}
```

It's a thread pool using Java 8. A very simple and esay way to make it using the Executors. Very staraight forward way to make it.

Comment: Good approach, but you really should scale the workers back to simple `Runnable`.

Comment: Would this still work if each worker extended `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable` @chrylis?

Comment: Yes, because Thread implements Runnable, but this would be confusing and arguably abusive, as those e threads would never be started.

Comment: What do you mean by, "those e threads would never be started." ? @FelixLeipold

Comment: The executor would either start or reuse a thread that then just calls the run-method of the Thread you pass in without ever callng thread start.

Comment: I see, so `Runnable` is the better option for use with executors @FelixLeipold

Comment: Yes. You should always use the minimal effort. Also, in Java 8 you can implement single method interfaces using the closure syntax.

Comment: @ylun.ca Just instantiating the thread object can involve significant OS resources, which aren't really needed for sequential short-lived tasks.

Comment: The ExecutorService#awaitTermination method should be used to wait for the execution to terminate. It doesn't keep the CPU busy and asks for a timeout, which is generally a good idea for concurrent operations. Also, the ExecutorService is not a Java 8 feature, but was introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will definitely be implementing this in favour of speed.  Also, turns out that my `.isAlive` method was broken somehow (wtf jvm) and after implementing my own version of the method, my tests now work.

Answer (score 3):

I reduced your code to this test case:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    private static class SleepThread extends Thread {
        private final int index;
        SleepThread(int ii) { index = ii; }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Creating thread " + this.index);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finished " + this.index);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numThreads = 2;
        int index = 0;
        SleepThread[] dlThreads = new SleepThread[numThreads];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii) {
            while (dlThreads[index] != null && dlThreads[index].isAlive()) {
                index += 1;
                index = index % numThreads;
            }
            dlThreads[index] = new SleepThread(index);
            dlThreads[index].start();
            index += 1;
            index = index % numThreads;
        }
    }
}
```

Using Sun JDK 1.7.0_75, running this produces the result that you'd expect--two threads start, they exit after five seconds, two more threads start, and so on.

The next thing I'd suspect is that your JVM's implementation of `Thread.isAlive()` isn't returning true for threads immediately after they are started, although that seems contrary to the documentation for the `Thread` class.

Comment: Hi, yea I printed the values for `.isAlive()` and it turns out that it is returning false every time, contrary to what documentation says. Do you know what could be the wrong?

Comment: So I ended up implementing my own version of `.isAlive` and the tests now work.. weird, but thanks.

Comment: @ylun.ca have you checked [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140731/isalive-method-of-java-thread-is-not-working-properly)?

Comment: @eis looking at that post, it seems like the answers don't really apply to this, the operation that the threads do takes longer than a few hundred milliseconds, so my calls to `.isAlive` should be working. Also, the second answer for that post, suggesting the thread could have already died, is not the case with my code, since the custom `isAlive` method I wrote also checks for if the run method has completed running. This is weird!

Comment: @ylun.ca there is also mention that *calling* thread should sleep for a short while. You could test that as well.

Comment: True, but this should all be errors also existant within my custom `isAlive` method, but mine works, which doesn't really make sense to me. @eis

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the above code wasn't working was because of something wacky going on with the call to `isAlive()`.

For some reason, no matter what state a thread is in, `isAlive()` will always return `false` for me, causing the creation of more and more threads, which replace the old ones in the array, `dlThreads`.

I solved the issue by creating a custom `isWorking()` method which simply returns a boolean of whether or not the thread's `run()` method has completed. Here is what the `Thread` class looks like now:

```
//this.isWorking initialized to true during instantiation

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Creating thread " + this.threadnum + " for " + filePath + "/" + fileName);
        this.fileObj = this.S3CLIENT.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(this.filePath, this.fileName));
        this.fileIn = new Scanner(new GZIPInputStream(this.fileObj.getObjectContent()));
        while (this.fileIn.hasNext()) {
            this.parent.forwardToTable(fileIn.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("Finished " + this.threadnum);
        this.isWorking = false;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Downloading of " + this.fileName + " failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.isWorking = false;
    }
}

public boolean isWorking(){
    return this.isWorking;
}
```

However, after implementing this and being satisfied that my multithreaded script works, I switched over to using an `Executor`, as suggested by other users, which slightly improved performance and made the code much cleaner.